# AsyncTask issue, am I doing it wrong?

Tags: java, android, json, http, android-asynctask

So I got this class that is suppose to fetch a jsonfile and then parse it into a jsonObject that will later be turn into a List of Calendar instances that I will deal with in my fragment.

Currently I am doing both the request and parsing of the json object in doInBackground function and returns a List of Calendar instances. I have almost no experiences with threads nor AsyncTask in android studios.

However I get the following error (See logcat)

```
09-19 20:08:46.614 13504-13504/com.abc.socke.abcE/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.abc.socke.abc, PID: 13504
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.abc.socke.abc.Calendar cannot be cast to java.util.List
        at com.abc.socke.abc.CalendarFragment.onCreateView(CalendarFragment.java:46)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2354)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2199)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:651)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1236)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:662)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:624)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:605)
        at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.onTabSelected(TabLayout.java:2170)
        at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.dispatchTabSelected(TabLayout.java:1165)
        at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1158)
        at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1128)
        at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1427)
        at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.performClick(TabLayout.java:1537)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Which directs me to this line in my Fragment where I am trying to make this call.

```
calendarEvents = (List<Calendar>) new Calendar().execute("https://api.myjson.com/bins/7cp25");
```

Questions: 
What am I doing wrong?

Should I parse my http request into a JsonObject and then create my Calendar instances in onPostExecute instead of doInBackground?

Try for any help guys!

```
package com.MyAppName.Myname.MyAppName;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.GraphResponse;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class Calendar extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Calendar>> {

    private String SUMMARY;
    private String DTSTART;
    private String data;
    public static final String REQUEST_METHOD = "GET";
    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 15000;


    public String getEventSummary() {
        return SUMMARY;
    }

    public String getEventTime() {
        return DTSTART;
    }


    public Calendar(String eventName, String etimeStamp) {
        SUMMARY = eventName;
        DTSTART = etimeStamp;
    }

    public Calendar() {
    }


    @Override
    protected List<Calendar> doInBackground(String... params) {

        String inputUrl = params[0];
        Log.v("PARAMS[0] URL: ", inputUrl);


        try {
            URL url = new URL(inputUrl);

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            //Set methods and timeouts
            connection.setRequestMethod(REQUEST_METHOD);
            connection.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

            //Connect to our url
            connection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            while (line != null) {
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                data = data + line;

            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        System.out.println("FETCHCALENDAREVENT");


        List<Calendar> allCalendarEvents = new ArrayList<Calendar>();

        try {
            JSONObject JsonData = new JSONObject(data);
            JSONArray data = JsonData.getJSONArray("VEVENT");

            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonData = data.getJSONObject(i);
                String event_name = jsonData.getString("SUMMARY");
                String timeStamp = jsonData.getString("DTSTART;VALUE=DATE");


                Calendar calendarEvent = new Calendar(event_name, timeStamp);
                allCalendarEvents.add(calendarEvent);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.v("KOM HIT", "SKODKSODSODKOS");
        Log.v("all allCalendarEvents!", allCalendarEvents.get(2).getEventSummary());

        return allCalendarEvents;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(List<Calendar>  allCalendarEvents) {
        super.onPostExecute(allCalendarEvents);
    }

}
```

UPDATE: I tried doing my stuff in onPostExecute instead. However what's wrong here?:

```
ArrayList<String> calendarItems = new ArrayList<String>();

CalendarFragment.listView = CalendarFragment.view.findViewById(R.id.calendar_list_view);

for(int i = 0; i < allCalendarEvents.size(); i++){

    calendarItems.add(i, allCalendarEvents.get(i).getEventSummary().toString() + "\n" + allCalendarEvents.get(i).getEventTime().toString());
}

if(CalendarFragment.listView != null){
    ArrayAdapter<String> listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            CalendarFragment.context,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
            calendarItems);
    CalendarFragment.listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
```

I replaced getActivity() with CalendarFragment.context so that it would update the correct one, I also called on CalendarFragment.listview. Should I have done this in another way?

Comment: `calendarEvents = (List<Calendar>) new Calendar().execute` is wrong move the assigment into the onPostExecute using a callback. If you need help, just tell to make you a small sample.

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
calendarEvents = (List<Calendar>) new Calendar().execute("https://api.myjson.com/bins/7cp25");
```

You are trying to cast a `Calendar` instace (it's your `AsyncTask` instance returned by the execute() method) to `List`. It's absolutely different types - that's why you get `ClassCastException`.

More than that you're doing quite strange thing in your code: you're parametrizing your `AsyncTask` task with a list of same AsyncTasks as result type. I highly doubt that it was your intention.

Comment: Could one solution to be separating the HTTP request with the Calendar Class instance. That is in my onCreate in my Fragment I first call the HTTP class to fetch the results and then I simply call my Calendar class and convert it to json objects and return lists of that that class instance?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a slight misunderstanding of AsyncTask.

The problem is that you are creating an AsyncTask object and attempting to assign it to a object of type List.  Hence, the exception is thrown.

In the AsyncTask `doInBackground`, you perform your work.  The return statement fires when the work is complete:

```
return allCalendarEvents;
```

That object, in this case a list of Calender objects, is returned to the AsyncTask `onPostExecute` method.

You want to do something useful with your list inside the `doInBackground`.  You can hand it back to the class that calls `.execute` or you can do some other action, it's up to you.

Comment: Could one solution to be separating the HTTP request with the Calendar Class instance. That is in my onCreate in my Fragment I first call the HTTP class to fetch the results and then I simply call my Calendar class and convert it to json objects and return lists of that that class instance?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to pass data back from AsyncTask class to your caller class. With your execute statement you are hoping to return a List. I am assuming that you think the return value of doInBackground() (which in your case is List) would be returned by the execute() call. That is wrong. That's not how AsyncTask works. The return value of doInBackground() is given to onPostExecute() as result.

What you want is an interface implementation. 
Inside your Calendar class

```
public interface IfaceCalendar {
    void onCalendaruResult(List<Calendar> list);
}

public IfaceCalendar listener;

public void SetListener(IfaceCalendar listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

So the above code sets up an interface which can return results to your caller fragment asynchronously.

You should call the listener using `listener.onCalendarResult(list)`. However this statement should not be inside your doInBackground(). doInBackground runs on a background thread. You want to return these results in a UI thread. So override the onPostExecute() function of AsyncTask and return the results through there.

```
@Override
public void onPostExecute(List<Calendar> list)
{
    if (listener != null) {
        listener.onCalendarResult(list);
    }
}
```

Lastly you will need to set the listener in your fragment before executing the task

```
Calendar c = new Calendar();
c.SetListener(this);
c.execute("https://api.myjson.com/bins/7cp25");
```

You can override the onCalendarResult() function in your fragment, receive the results and do whatever you want. Here's how its implemented :

```
@Override
public void onCalendarResult(List<Calendar> list) {
    // You have your list here. Do what you want with it
}
```

Comment: Ty for response. I'm considering trying your solution soon. 

Could one solution to be separating the HTTP request with the Calendar Class instance. That is in my onCreate in my Fragment I first call the HTTP class to fetch the results and then I simply call my Calendar class and convert it to json objects and return lists of that that class instance?

Comment: Even if you do that, you don't have any guarantee when the Http request will complete. Learning about interfaces and using them with AsyncTask is a good method and will help you out later too. So i recommend just suck it up and learn it :P . Learn the basics of AsyncTask and interfaces and you are good to implement any background operation instead of adding hacks in your code.

Comment: That is true! It's better to learn the constructions rather than writing spaghetti code :P 
One question: Is the onCalendaruResult suppose to implemented in my Fragment or my Calendar class? And what should it do and contain?

Comment: It should be in your fragment. Edited the answer with how to override it.

Comment: It says Method does not override from its superclass. I think the reason behind that is because I have yet defined onCalendarResult in my fragment CalendarFragment.java file.

In my onCreate method I need to have my list. Unfortunately the onCalendarResult() cannot be called in the onCreate since I don't have the a List<Calendar> there.

Comment: You also have to add `implements Calendar.IfaceCalendar` to your CalendarFragement class declaration. So the declaration would look something like this `public class CalendarFragment extends Fragment implements Calendar.IfaceCalendar {...`

Comment: I'm suppose to add the contents into a listView in the onCreate basically

Comment: Well than thats a design issue. You want to get the list asynchronously form the server and yet you want add it to a listview as soon as activity is created. You need to fix your design. If you are requesting data asynchronously, you should have some provision in UI to wait and update when data is received. Your listView's update should be inside the onCalendarResult override. In onCreate you can just initialize the listview and leave it empty. This means that when you open the activity, the list would be blank and would update itself after some time. Not the best solution, but the simplest.

Comment: So how do I proceed with the current code you given me?

Comment: Your listView's update should be inside the onCalendarResult override. In onCreate you can just initialize the listview and leave it empty. This means that when you open the activity, the list would be blank and would update itself after some time. Not the best solution, but the simplest.

Comment: OK cool! :D One question came up right now, where do I take the json http address as input at the moment?

EDIT: Just realized where. I added the address to c.execute("address here");

Comment: Same way you have been doing till now. My Bad. `c.execute("https://api.myjson.com/bins/7cp25");`. Edited the answer too.

Comment: I solved the error  by adding  if(listView != null). However no items are made. Probably since nothing is added to the listview since it's always null :/

Comment: Siddharth, it doesn't really seem that the inparameter list contains anything in the onCalendarResult function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154923/discussion-between-sockevalley-and-siddharth-garg).